# How do you check for end of line in c++?

Tags: c++

I have to accept space separated integers from user but stop when i encounter a new line.
For example:

```
3 5 7 9
23 47
6
```

In this example I must store `3, 5, 7, 9` in array 1, `23, 47` in array 2, `6` in array 3.
Unfortunately, I don't know how to check for the end of line in C++. Please help me out.

Comment: Please show us the code you do have.

Answer (score 10):

The usual solution is to use `std::getline` to read line by line, then `std::istringstream` to parse each line.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe less simple but this is a code snippet I have been using for years to read in data files. Give it a string and a delimeter and it will return a vector of delimited strings. I normally use it to break up lines but if you have an odd character representing the end of a line I guess the same principle applies. I should say I didn't write it, but I have long forgotten where I found it.

```
Split(std::string& line, std::string& splitter)
{
  std::vector<std::string> result;
  if (!line.empty() && !splitter.empty())
  {
    for (std::string::size_type offset = 0;;)
    {
      std::string::size_type found = line.find(splitter, offset);
      if (found != std::string::npos)
      {
          std::string tmpString = line.substr(offset, found-offset);
          if (tmpString.size() > 0)
          {
                  result.push_back(tmpString);
          }
          offset = found + splitter.size();
      } else {
        std::string tmpString = line.substr(offset, line.size()-offset);

       if (tmpString.size() > 0)
        {
                result.push_back(tmpString);
        }
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```